# FL Studio hangs when I try to add any plugins to the mixer

Tags: audio

I'm running FL Studio 20 on Windows 10. The issue is when I have my audio interface inputs added to an Insert on the mixer, whenever I try to add a plugin (a reverb for instance) to any slot on any Insert, it just stops playing (basically the UI is useless, buttons can be selected but don't actually work) until I reset the input of my audio interface on the host Insert. I turn it to none and then turn it back to whatever input was selected (In1 for instance in the figure below) and then it goes back to being good. But when I load a new preset or add a new plugin, it stops functioning all over again. The issue is non-existent when I don't have an audio interface setup. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: You’ll probably have better luck on an FL Studio support forum or support chat

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a basic customer support issue, best referred to the developer.

Comment: If you have purchased FL studio, you can raise this issue on the official image-line forums